# Git setting up ssh key

Tags: git, heroku, ssh, key, git-clone

I installed git on a machine using Windows Xp and I am trying to clone from a remote repository hosted on heroku. The problem is that when I first login on heroku the generate ssh key option does not appear. Using `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your_email@example.com"` I created a ssh key (or so does git bash say), however if I go to the folder, it only contains the `known_hosts` file. System and Hidden files are visible. 
Since the generate ssh option did not show up, I suppose there is already an existent ssh, however it doesn't fit- because I get a permission denied error when trying to clone the repo.
Any idea how should I solve this?

Answer (score 6):

See what the name of your key is on Heroku with this command:

```
heroku keys
```

Remove it:

```
heroku keys:remove your_key
```

Generate a new SSH key

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your_email@example.com"
```

Add it to Heroku:

```
heroku keys:add
```

Comment: I finally solved it- but I really have no idea how. Just tried all sort of things

Comment: Haha, well I'm glad you got it working! If you have any idea on some of the steps you took, you may want to submit an answer to your own question, for others who may experience the same issue.

Comment: I think i just repeted clear keys and heroku keys:add until I got it working.

Answer (score 0):

Enter a following line of code

**heroku keys:add**

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys#adding-keys-to-heroku